# Errors when trying to use import java.util.Scanner

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to coding and I'm going through an online course (MOOC). I'm on a section about reading user input and I copy-pasted the code from the website into Netbeans but I'm getting errors like illegal start of expression and not a statement. Here's my code:

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class ProgramName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                // code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get illegal start of expression for the import and public class lines. I also get a not a statement error for the import line. Lastly I get illegal static declaration for the public static void line.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Import should reside outside the class declaration (read, import comes before public class)

Comment: It seems you have an extra parenthesis at the end. Also you just need one class and one method to test your code like: 
```import java.util.Scanner;
    public class ProgramName {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        // code here
    }```

Comment: Why do you have a method inside a class inside a method inside a class?

Comment: Because I don't know what I'm doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import goes here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        // code here

    }
}
```

It is not a property of the class but a reference the compiler needs to be able to tell what "Scanner" (in this context) refers to. In this case it states that Scanner is defined in `java.util` which is part of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

Furthermore as you go on coding you should structure your files into folders.
As soon as you do so you will have to add this type of line in the first line of the file: `package folderName.folderName0`.
If you want to use one of your classes from another one you will have to add an import like: `import folderName.folderName0.JavaApplication2`

Answer (score 1):

You've put an entire java source file into a `main` function. Simply do this instead:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot put import and package statements **inside a class**. They should be done before class definitions.

Try this code:-

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    // import before class definition.

    public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        public class ProgramName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

            // code here
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this in the header of the page  : `import java.util.Scanner;`

Answer (score 0):

you missing import important  : `import java.util.Scanner;`

***Exmple :***

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class JavaApplication2 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        import java.util.Scanner;
        public class ProgramName {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
                // code here
            }
        }
    }
}
```